# Problems in Android using Zendesk and Action Bar Sherlock - Attribute has already been defined

Tags: android, gradle, actionbarsherlock, zendesk

I want to use the Zendesk Android SDK within my project, wich already uses ActionBarSherlock. When I installed the Zendesk SDK using gradle(like they teach here https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/android/gettingstarted ) I got lots of "Atribute has already been defined" from goggle play-services wallet_colors.xml.
Doing some tests like creating a new project and adding my dependencies, I figured out that ActionBarSherlock was the problem, but I need it. Have anybody gone through this problem?

Here my gradle file:

```
repositories {
maven { url 'https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo' }
}
dependencies {
compile project(':facebookSDK')
compile project(':library')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
compile 'com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android:3.2.4'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.1.0'
compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7'
compile files('libs/crashlytics.jar')
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.2'
compile group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'sdk', version: '1.0.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

Comment: How did you fix this ?!

Comment: @SysHex removed actionbar sherlock from my project, and used appcompat v7 instead. this link should help https://www.grokkingandroid.com/migrating-actionbarsherlock-actionbarcompat/